# mysql join where for 1 table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 2 tables, student and grades
student table contains id, name and date_of_birth
grades table contains id, student_id, grade and course
Actual table contain more data.

I have a query like

```
SELECT s.*, AVG(g.grade) as average_grade 
FROM student s LEFT JOIN grade g ON s,id = g.student_id 
WHERE g.course = 'mathematics' and s.id = 1
```

With this I could get the data i needed which are student details and the average grade, then come the problem where when the `course = "mathematics"` is not found in the grades table, the query will return NULL. My question is, is there a way for me to get the `s.id = 1` details together with NULL average instead of all NULL value?

I would prefer if it is able to do it with 1 query, as because in my current I am using subquery and it takes very long to get the data. My main objective is to get more faster speed if you have better way instead of using 1 query feel free to comment your idea. In addition I have tried multiple query and sub query to get all the data but it all take too long.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Ask again, differently.

Comment: you have a syntax error on your sql query near `s,id`. should be `s.id`

Comment: I think what you're asking could be solved using `WHERE (g.course='math' OR g.course IS NULL) AND s.id = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your filter criteria for `g.course = 'mathematics'` in joining part

```
SELECT s.*, AVG(g.grade) as average_grade 
FROM student s 
LEFT JOIN grade g ON s.id = g.student_id AND g.course = 'mathematics'
WHERE  s.id = 1
```

Your query produces result as inner join not left because putting `g.course = 'mathematics` in where clause turns your left join to inner join, Moving this part in `on` clause will still return data from `student` table if there were no rows found from `grade` table with `course = 'mathematics'`

Answer (score 0):

If the course is not 'mathematics' you would still get the student data if you put it like this.

```
SELECT s.*, AVG(g.grade) as average_grade 
FROM student s LEFT JOIN grade g ON s,id = g.student_id 
WHERE (g.course = 'mathematics' AND s.id = 1) OR s.id = 1
```